# Serial Port / C# / Seems to ignore sending \r\n

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

Been working with the serial port in C# and one particular device is vexing me.

The device accepts commands using H-Term (http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/) and works as expected:

1. I send a command,
2. terminate with \r,
3. it responds with an answer

I try to reproduce this in C# and I'm running into a lot of trouble.  The crux of the matter is that it ignores the command.

The device appears to be waiting for \r.  I know this based upon (x2) experiments:

1. I use the MSDN example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

I insert

```
_serialport.WriteLine("command");
```

and allow the example to continue to take input from the console.  If I type , the command will execute.  If I do not, the device ignores the command.

I've tried several variations on this theme, including:

```
_serialport.WriteLine("command\r\n");

_serialport.Write("command" + (byte) 10 + (byte) 13);

string message = "command" + (byte) 10 + (byte) 13;    
_serialport.WriteLine(message);

string message = "command" + (byte) 10 + (byte) 13);    
_serialport.Write(message);
```

All have the same result.  If I don't type  using the MSDN example, the device will not respond.  If I type , somehow the device listens to the MSDN sample code sending the \r on  and it responds to the command. I have tried various combinations of

```
_serialPort.NewLine = ...
```

and none resolve the issue.

Looking at the MSDN (code snippet), it is just a simple WriteLine!?

```
    while (_continue)
    {
        message = Console.ReadLine();

        if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
        {
            _continue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _serialPort.WriteLine(
                String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
        }
    }
```

2. If I write a simple C# program with:

   _serialPort.WriteLine(command)

and all the variations above, then I pause the C# program and go to H-Term and I send a \n, it accepts the command!

It seems that the WriteLine is not consistently sending the \n.  Is this possible?  If not, what are the other possibilities?

Comment: Have you tried setting cultureinfo to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and also sending a `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: Not yet.  The PC is configured for United States and all H/W is designed for the United States.  With this information, do you still suspect that there is an issue?

Comment: I think you want to send a `<CR><LF>` at the end and you are sending a `<LF><CR>`.  `char CR = (char)13; char LF = (char)10;`  So you should be sending a 13 first then a 10.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks... turns out it was not my fault.  It was a H/W issue!

That being said, the most stable way to communicate w/the H/W appears to be:

```
serialPort.Write(stringMessage + (char) 13 + (char) 10)
```

instead of configuring

```
WriteLine()
```

Should there be a difference?